# Infinite integral of $1/(1+x^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Given the theorem that the infinite integral of $1/x^n$ is convergent if and only if $n>1$, I want to prove that the infinite integral of $1/(1+x^2)$ exists. This seems like a trivial question, I know, and one can calculate the integral by other means but I'd like to understand the argument from a book I'm reading.

Comment: From what lower limit ?

Comment: What is the argument this book makes?

Comment: From -$\infty$ to +$\infty$

Comment: @derthomas: Since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is an even function, it is enough to consider the integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Thank you this answers my question. @abiessu it says that by the theorem written in my question the infinite integral of the function $1/(1+x^2)$ exists

Comment: @derthomas I would just like to mention that we must be careful with $1/x^a$ around $x=0$ as well as around $x=+\infty$: For $a>1$ it is convergent at $+\infty$, and for $a<1$ it is convergent at $x=0$.

Comment: What do you mean by "convergent at..."? What does it have to do with this integral and where is the caution required?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split up the integral into two pieces:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\int_{0}^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}+\int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2} $$
The first integral presents no problems, and for the second integral we have
$$ \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\leq \int_1^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^2}<\infty $$
since $\frac{1}{1+x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x^2}$ on $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: One could split at any $a>0$, right?

Comment: That's right. The key is to avoid the discontinuity of $\frac{1}{x^2}$ at $0$.